# How to record video in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to record video using my webcam. And this process developed using asp.net. But currently, I cannot do this. I can only access webcam access but cannot save webcam video record. So, anyone please help with this problem.

Comment: We need more details on what your problem is, and how are you trying to solve it.
If you need to just to upload file see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: I cannot develop a video calling system using asp.net.